# Не удается получить данные из консоли во время теста на Java (TestNG)

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, test-automation, scanner, testng

Пишу автотест для сайта, на котором обязательна авторизация по номеру телефона. На указанный номер приходит смс с кодом, который надо ввести. Вопрос заключается в том, как реализовать ввод этого кода в процессе теста.
Пробовала через Scanner, но на моменте ввода кода все застревает, не могу ничего ввести в консоли

```
 @Test
public void AddPatientToArchive() throws IOException {
    File file = new File("src/test/resources/chromedriver.exe");
    System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", file.getAbsolutePath());
    WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
    driver.navigate().to("https://cardiopro.mts.ru");
    WebElement phoneField = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@name='login']"));
    phoneField.sendKeys("");  //тут номер телефона
    WebElement furtherButton = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//span[@class='button__content']"));
    furtherButton.click();
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Enter code from SMS:");
    String code = scan.nextLine();
    WebElement codeGaps = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@class='codeCheckBlock__codeCheck codeCheck -hidden -hideButton']"));
    codeGaps.sendKeys(code);
}
```

[image: ввод]

Comment: Я правильно понимаю что Вы хотите при каждом запуске теста вводить код из SMS-ки? Устроят ли Вас альтернативные варианты: (1) поставить заглушку, (2) автоматизировать получение SMS?

Comment: @defaultlocale вообще да, изначально идея была вводить смс каждый раз, но с радостью рассмотрю и альтернативные варианты.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Вводить SMS

Вводить SMS при каждом запуске это довольно неудобное решение. Тесты пишутся для того чтобы они работали автоматически, без участия человека. Библиотеки тестов (TestNG в данном случае) подставляют свой поток ввода и поэтому считывать через `System.in` не получится.

Но если нужно только так и не иначе, то можно вывести тестировщику диалог для ввода SMS:

```
String code = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter sms");
```

[image: Диалог]

### Альтернатива: заглушка

В качестве альтернативы можно поставить заглушку на SMS. Для этого нужно запускать тесты на тестовой версии сайта и предусмотреть возможность подменять сервис отправки SMS на свой. В тесте при этом будет проверяться не то, что пришло SMS, а то что сервис был вызван с корректными параметрами.

Еще, если код сохраняется в БД, то можно получать его оттуда и игнорировать отправленное сообщение.

### Альтернатива: получать SMS автоматически.

Также можно реализовать получение SMS в коде теста. Варианты можете посмотреть здесь: [How to automate OTP using selenium web driver?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36026904/how-to-automate-otp-using-selenium-web-driver). Приведу несколько здесь:

- Подключить телефон к компьютеру и получать SMS через smslib либо appium.
- Использовать сервисы автоматизации, например IFTTT, чтобы переслать SMS на более доступный для теста ресурс (email, файл и т.п.) и прочитать его оттуда.
- Подключиться к SMS шлюзу и арендовать там SIM-карту или виртуальный номер.

Comment: огромное спасибо, Вы мне очень помогли!)

Comment: @AnnaShevchenko Пожалуйста! Всех благ! :)